# Copy whole field from one entity to another

Tags: 7, entities, rules

i want to copy a field from one entity to another while processing a rule.
my current code looks like this:

```
<?php
    $entity_created->field_ort = $entity_fetched->field_ort;
?>
```

but instead i get an error message:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (Zeile 3 von /www/www/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(125) : eval()'d code).
```

so i found this site http://drupal.org/node/1000200 which tells me that i need to do this more like this:

```
<?php
    $entity_created->field_ort['und'][0]['value'] = $entity_fetched->field_ort['und'][0]['value'];
?>
```

but what about lists and other fields? is there a more generic approach? i need to copy about 5 or more fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue and the following code seems to have no bearing on the opening problem. Trying to get property of non-object, it literally means that $entity_fetched is not an object. Dump it into a file to see what it is.

Comment: yes, you are right... `$entity_fetched` is a List of Entities... right below it i used `$entity_fetched[0]->field...` and totaly oversaw that